# Find the biggest number among two using only one if condition?

Tags: java

Today was my first class at the institute for java developer course. The lecturer put forward a question for the whole class:

> Find the biggest number among two numbers by using only one condition, i.e., **if condition only**. Do not use any other conditions like using if-else, else-if, using if two times, ternary, loops, etc.

Comment: welcome to SO. Please provide what you have done so far. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Since you are learning Java, I recommend you trying first before asking. If you did try, you must post your solution as well. If you just ask for answer, it wouldn’t really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int first = 10;
int second = 20;
int max = first;
if (second > max) {
    max = second;
}
System.out.println(max);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
int max = a;

if (b > a) {
    max = b;
}
```